# How to access user input from radio buttons (made with a JS callback) in shiny DT and have different JS elements in one DT?

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny, datatables

I am trying to combine two commonly shared JS callbacks into one R datatable shiny app (having radio buttons (see https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-radio/ and [Extracting user input values from radio buttons in Shiny DT into a dataframe or list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66257163/extracting-user-input-values-from-radio-buttons-in-shiny-dt-into-a-dataframe-or)) and having nested rows in a child/parent table (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56599838/10624798 and many other places). Individually they both work, but not together. I am not sure if I incorrectly bound the JS or that the JS somehow contradicts each other? Either way, I am not able to access the user input anymore (just a null returns if I look at the structure of the input$xxx). I have included a small example (although still quite lengthy) of what I mean.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Radio button and a dropdown manue ',
    sliderInput("n_rows_table", "Number of rows:",
                min = 0, max = 10,
                value = 5),
    actionBttn(
      inputId = "btnCancel",
      label = "Make tables",
      size = "sm",
      color = "warning"
    ),
    p("THIS EXAMPLE DOES NOT WORK!"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("datatable"),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel'),
    p("THIS SIMPLER EXAMPLE DOES WORK!"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("datatable2"),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel2'),
    p("These of the R6 input class objects, the the ones from the first tabel do not show up"),
    
    verbatimTextOutput('sel_all'),
    
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    

    # Ideally instead of working with a counter,
    # this would just override the old value so instead of a_1, a_2,
    # everything you click the button it just sets input$a back to null
    # until the users clicks again. 
    # But in the meantime this is a work around
    
    counter <- reactiveValues(countervalue = 0) # Defining & initializing the reactiveValues object
    
    observeEvent(input$btnCancel, {
      counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue + 1     # if the add button is clicked, increment the value by 1 and update it
    })
    
    
    # ----- Create a table based on the number of rows from the slider
    # ----- and create it when the user clicks the button
    data_for_table <-  eventReactive(
      input$btnCancel,
      {
        tibble(
          let_rowid = paste0(letters[1:input$n_rows_table],  "_", counter$countervalue ),
          val_1 = round(runif(input$n_rows_table, 0, 10), 1),
          val_2 = round(rnorm(input$n_rows_table), 2),
          val_3 = round(rnorm(input$n_rows_table), 2),
          val_4 = letters[1:input$n_rows_table],
          Yes   = "Yes",
          No    = "No",
          Maybe = "Maybe",
          result = NA # ideally the what ever selection in yes/no/maybe shows up in this column (future improvement)
        )  %>%
          mutate(oplus = "&oplus;") %>%
          relocate(oplus) %>%
          mutate(
            Yes =  sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>', let_rowid , Yes),
            No =  sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>', let_rowid , No),
            Maybe =  sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>', let_rowid ,  Maybe)
          ) %>%
          nest(datalist = c(val_3, val_4)) %>%
          mutate(datalist = map(datalist, as.list)) %>%
          mutate(datalist = map(datalist, list))
        
      })
    
    # ----- Render the table
    # ----- The table renders ok.
    output$datatable <- DT::renderDT({
      parentRows <- which(data_for_table()[,1] != "")
      
      # ------ This JS is neede to make the child/parent dropdown
      callback <- JS(
        sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
        sprintf("var j0 = %d;", 0),
        "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
        "for(let i = 0; i < nrows; ++i){",
        "  var $cell = table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$();",
        "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
        "    $cell.css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
        "  }else{",
        "    $cell.removeClass('details-control');",
        "  }",
        "}",
        "",
        "// --- make the table header of the nested table --- //",
        "var formatHeader = function(d, childId){",
        "  if(d !== null){",
        "    var html = ",
        "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
        "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + ",
        "      '\"><thead><tr>';",
        "    var data = d[d.length-1] || d.datalist;",
        "    for(let key in data[0]){",
        "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
        "    }",
        "    html += '</tr></thead></table>'",
        "    return html;",
        "  } else {",
        "    return '';",
        "  }",
        "};",
        "",
        "// --- row callback to style rows of child tables --- //",
        "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
        "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
        "    $(row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
        "    $(row).hover(function(){",
        "      $(this).css('background-color', '#E6FF99');",
        "    }, function(){",
        "      $(this).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
        "    });",
        "  } else {",
        "    $(row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
        "    $(row).hover(function(){",
        "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDFF75');",
        "    }, function(){",
        "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
        "    });",
        "  }",
        "};",
        "",
        "// --- header callback to style header of child tables --- //",
        "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
        "  $('th', thead).css({",
        "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',",
        "    'color': 'indigo',",
        "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
        "  });",
        "};",
        "",
        "// --- make the datatable --- //",
        "var formatDatatable = function(d, childId){",
        "  var data = d[d.length-1] || d.datalist;",
        "  var colNames = Object.keys(data[0]);",
        "  var columns = colNames.map(function(x){",
        "    return {data: x.replace(/\\./g, '\\\\\\.'), title: x};",
        "  });",
        "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
        "  if(colNames.indexOf('datalist') === -1){",
        "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
        "      'data': data,",
        "      'columns': columns,",
        "      'autoWidth': true,",
        "      'deferRender': true,",
        "      'info': false,",
        "      'lengthChange': false,",
        "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
        "      'order': [],",
        "      'paging': false,",
        "      'scrollX': false,",
        "      'scrollY': false,",
        "      'searching': false,",
        "      'sortClasses': false,",
        "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
        "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
        "      'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
        "    });",
        "  } else {",
        "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
        "      'data': data,",
        "      'columns': columns,",
        "      'autoWidth': true,",
        "      'deferRender': true,",
        "      'info': false,",
        "      'lengthChange': false,",
        "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
        "      'order': [],",
        "      'paging': false,",
        "      'scrollX': false,",
        "      'scrollY': false,",
        "      'searching': false,",
        "      'sortClasses': false,",
        "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
        "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
        "      'columnDefs': [",
        "        {targets: -1, visible: false},",
        "        {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},",
        "        {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
        "      ]",
        "    }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
        "  }",
        "};",
        "",
        "// --- display the child table on click --- //",
        "// array to store id's of already created child tables",
        "var children = [];",
        "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
        "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
        "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
        "      td = $(this),",
        "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
        "      rowIdx = row.index();",
        "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
        "    row.child.hide();",
        "    td.html('&oplus;');",
        "  } else {",
        "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
        "    if(children.indexOf(childId) === -1){",
        "      // this child has not been created yet",
        "      children.push(childId);",
        "      row.child(formatHeader(row.data(), childId)).show();",
        "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
        "      formatDatatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
        "    }else{",
        "      // this child has already been created",
        "      row.child(true);",
        "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
        "    }",
        "  }",
        "}); ",
        "// --- add radio button functionality --- //",
        "table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {",
        "                    var $this = $(this.node());",
        "                    $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);", 
        "                    $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');",
        "  });",
        "           Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());",
        "           Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
      
      
      datatable(
        data_for_table(),
        escape = F,
        rownames = F,
        callback = callback,
        options = list(
          dom = 't',
          paging = FALSE,
          ordering = FALSE,
          paging = FALSE,
          searching = FALSE,
          columnDefs = list(
            list(
              visible = FALSE, 
              targets = c(c(1, ncol(data_for_table())-1)) # do not show certain ID variables, we do not need 
            ),
            list(
              orderable = FALSE, 
              className = "details-control", 
              targets = 0
            ),
            list(
              className = "dt-left", 
              targets = "_all"
            )
          )
        )
        
      )
    },
    server = F)
    
    
    list_results <- reactive({
      list_values <- list()
      for (i in unique(data_for_table()$let_rowid)) {
        list_values[[i]] <- paste0(i, ": ", input[[i]])
        
      }
      list_values
    })
    
    output$sel = renderPrint({
      list_results()
    })
    
    

    
    ####################################
    ## this simpler version does work ##
    ####################################
    
    data_for_table2 <-  eventReactive(
      input$btnCancel,
      {
        tibble(
          let_rowid = paste0(letters[11:(10+input$n_rows_table)],  "_", counter$countervalue ),
          val_1 = round(runif(input$n_rows_table, 0, 10), 1),
          val_2 = round(rnorm(input$n_rows_table), 2),
          val_3 = round(rnorm(input$n_rows_table), 2),
          val_4 = letters[1:input$n_rows_table],
          Yes   = "Yes",
          No    = "No",
          Maybe = "Maybe",
          result = NA # ideally the what ever selection in yes/no/maybe shows up in this column (future improvement)
        )  %>%
          mutate(
            Yes =  sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>', let_rowid , Yes),
            No =  sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>', let_rowid , No),
            Maybe =  sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>', let_rowid ,  Maybe)
          )       })
    
    
    output$datatable2 <- DT::renderDT({
      
      # ---- only difference here is he lack of a drop down.
      callback <- JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                    var $this = $(this.node());
                    $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                    $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
  });
                    Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                    Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
      
      
      datatable(
        data_for_table2(),
        escape = F,
        rownames = F,
        callback = callback,
        options = list(
          dom = 't',
          paging = FALSE,
          ordering = FALSE,
          paging = FALSE,
          searching = FALSE,
          columnDefs = list(
            # list(
            #   visible = FALSE, 
            #   targets = c(ncol(data_for_table2())-1+0) # do not show certain ID variables, we do not need 
            # ),
            list(
              orderable = FALSE, 
              className = "details-control", 
              targets = 0
            ),
            list(
              className = "dt-left", 
              targets = "_all"
            )
          )
        )
        
      )
    },
    server = F)
    
    list_results2 <- reactive({
      list_values <- list()
      for (i in unique(data_for_table2()$let_rowid)) {
        list_values[[i]] <- paste0(i, ": ", input[[i]])
        
      }
      list_values
    })
    
    output$sel2 = renderPrint({
      list_results2()
    })
    
    
    # make this regex working
    list_results_all <- reactive({
      list_values_all <- list()
      for(i in names(input)[grepl("([a-z]{1}_)([0-9]{1,3})",names(input))]){
        list_values_all[[i]] <- tibble(id = i, value =  paste0(input[[i]]))
        
      }
      do.call(rbind, list_values_all)
      
    })
    
    
    output$sel_all = renderPrint({
      list_results_all()
    })
    
  }
)
```

### EDIT (ADDITIONAL QUESTION)

An answer was given that solved my original question for the MWE. However, diving into it a bit more and by adding extra types of buttons to the table the radio buttons still break (for example by adding a delete button, if I first click on the radio buttons and then the delete it does work, but not vice versa). Is there a way to make this behaviour more consistant?

(some of the code is taken from the answer on this question: [R Shiny: Remove Row Button in Data Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53908266/r-shiny-remove-row-button-in-data-table))

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)


# 1) These two function allows for setting a remove function in the app.
#   This code is taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53908266/r-shiny-remove-row-button-in-data-table

getRemoveButton <- function(n, idS = "", lab = "Pit") {
  if (stringr::str_length(idS) > 0) idS <- paste0(idS, "-")
  ret <- shinyInput(actionButton, n,
                    'button_', label = "Remove",
                    onclick = sprintf('Shiny.onInputChange(\"%sremove_button_%s\",  this.id)' ,idS, lab))
  return (ret)
}

shinyInput <- function(FUN, n, id, ses, ...) {
  as.character(FUN(paste0(id, n), ...))
}


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Radio button and a dropdown manue ',
    sliderInput("n_rows_table", "Number of rows:",
                min = 0, max = 10,
                value = 5),
    actionBttn(
      inputId = "btnCancel",
      label = "Make tables",
      size = "sm",
      color = "warning"
    ),
    p("THIS EXAMPLE DOES NOT WORK!"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("datatable"),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel'),
    #p("THIS SIMPLER EXAMPLE DOES WORK!"),
    #DT::dataTableOutput("datatable2"),
    #verbatimTextOutput('sel2'),
    #("These of the R6 input class objects, the the ones from the first tabel do not show up"),
    #verbatimTextOutput('sel_all'),
    
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    # Ideally instead of working with a counter,
    # this would just override the old value so instead of a_1, a_2,
    # everything you click the button it just sets input$a back to null
    # until the users clicks again. 
    # But in the meantime this is a work around
    
    counter <- reactiveValues(countervalue = 0) # Defining & initializing the reactiveValues object
    
    observeEvent(input$btnCancel, {
      counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue + 1     # if the add button is clicked, increment the value by 1 and update it
    })
    
    
    
    
    values <- reactiveValues(tab = NULL)
    
    
    # ----- Create a table based on the number of rows from the slider
    # ----- and create it when the user clicks the button
    observeEvent(
      input$btnCancel,
      {
        values$tab <-  tibble(
          let_rowid = paste0(letters[1:input$n_rows_table],  "_", counter$countervalue ),
          val_1 = round(runif(input$n_rows_table, 0, 10), 1),
          val_2 = round(rnorm(input$n_rows_table), 2),
          val_3 = round(rnorm(input$n_rows_table), 2),
          val_4 = letters[1:input$n_rows_table],
          Yes   = "Yes",
          No    = "No",
          Maybe = "Maybe",
          result = NA # ideally the what ever selection in yes/no/maybe shows up in this column (future improvement)
        )  %>%
          mutate(oplus = "&oplus;") %>%
          relocate(oplus) %>%
          mutate(
            Yes =  sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>', let_rowid , Yes),
            No =  sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>', let_rowid , No),
            Maybe =  sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>', let_rowid ,  Maybe)
          ) %>%
          ## THIS IS NEW ###################################################
           mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%                                           #
           rowwise() %>%                                                    #
           mutate(Remove = getRemoveButton(id, idS = "", lab = "Tab1"))%>%  #
           ungroup() %>%                                                    # 
          ##################################################################                                         
        nest(datalist = c(val_3, val_4)) %>%
          mutate(datalist = map(datalist, as.list)) %>%
          mutate(datalist = map(datalist, list)) 
        
      })
    
    # add a proxy table
    proxyTable <- DT::dataTableProxy("tab")
    
    
    # ----- Render the table
    # ----- The table renders ok.
    output$datatable <- DT::renderDT({
      parentRows <- which(values$tab[,1] != "")
      
      # ------ This JS is neede to make the child/parent dropdown
      callback <- JS(
       sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
        sprintf("var j0 = %d;", 0),
        "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
        "for(let i = 0; i < nrows; ++i){",
        "  var $cell = table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$();",
        "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
        "    $cell.css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
        "  }else{",
        "    $cell.removeClass('details-control');",
        "  }",
        "}",
        "",
        "// --- make the table header of the nested table --- //",
        "var formatHeader = function(d, childId){",
        "  if(d !== null){",
        "    var html = ",
        "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
        "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + ",
        "      '\"><thead><tr>';",
        "    var data = d[d.length-1] || d.datalist;",
        "    for(let key in data[0]){",
        "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
        "    }",
        "    html += '</tr></thead></table>'",
        "    return html;",
        "  } else {",
        "    return '';",
        "  }",
        "};",
        "",
        "// --- row callback to style rows of child tables --- //",
        "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
        "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
        "    $(row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
        "    $(row).hover(function(){",
        "      $(this).css('background-color', '#E6FF99');",
        "    }, function(){",
        "      $(this).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
        "    });",
        "  } else {",
        "    $(row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
        "    $(row).hover(function(){",
        "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDFF75');",
        "    }, function(){",
        "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
        "    });",
        "  }",
        "};",
        "",
        "// --- header callback to style header of child tables --- //",
        "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
        "  $('th', thead).css({",
        "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',",
        "    'color': 'indigo',",
        "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
        "  });",
        "};",
        "",
        "// --- make the datatable --- //",
        "var formatDatatable = function(d, childId){",
        "  var data = d[d.length-1] || d.datalist;",
        "  var colNames = Object.keys(data[0]);",
        "  var columns = colNames.map(function(x){",
        "    return {data: x.replace(/\\./g, '\\\\\\.'), title: x};",
        "  });",
        "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
        "  if(colNames.indexOf('datalist') === -1){",
        "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
        "      'data': data,",
        "      'columns': columns,",
        "      'autoWidth': true,",
        "      'deferRender': true,",
        "      'info': false,",
        "      'lengthChange': false,",
        "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
        "      'order': [],",
        "      'paging': false,",
        "      'scrollX': false,",
        "      'scrollY': false,",
        "      'searching': false,",
        "      'sortClasses': false,",
        "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
        "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
        "      'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
        "    });",
        "  } else {",
        "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
        "      'data': data,",
        "      'columns': columns,",
        "      'autoWidth': true,",
        "      'deferRender': true,",
        "      'info': false,",
        "      'lengthChange': false,",
        "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
        "      'order': [],",
        "      'paging': false,",
        "      'scrollX': false,",
        "      'scrollY': false,",
        "      'searching': false,",
        "      'sortClasses': false,",
        "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
        "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
        "      'columnDefs': [",
        "        {targets: -1, visible: false},",
        "        {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},",
        "        {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
        "      ]",
        "    }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
        "  }",
        "};",
        "",
        "// --- display the child table on click --- //",
        "// array to store id's of already created child tables",
        "var children = [];",
        "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
        "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
        "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
        "      td = $(this),",
        "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
        "      rowIdx = row.index();",
        "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
        "    row.child.hide();",
        "    td.html('&oplus;');",
        "  } else {",
        "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
        "    if(children.indexOf(childId) === -1){",
        "      // this child has not been created yet",
        "      children.push(childId);",
        "      row.child(formatHeader(row.data(), childId)).show();",
        "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
        "      formatDatatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
        "    }else{",
        "      // this child has already been created",
        "      row.child(true);",
        "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
        "    }",
        "  }",
        "}); ",
        "// --- add radio button functionality --- //",
        "table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {",
        "                    var $this = $(this.node());",
        "                    $this.attr('id', this.data()[1]);", 
        "                    $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');",
        "  });",
        "           Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());",
        "           Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
      
      
      datatable(
        values$tab,
        escape = F,
        rownames = F,
        callback = callback,
        options = list(
          dom = 't',
          paging = FALSE,
          ordering = FALSE,
          paging = FALSE,
          searching = FALSE,
          columnDefs = list(
             list(
               visible = FALSE, 
               targets = c(c(1, ncol(values$tab)-1)) # do not show certain ID variables, we do not need 
             ),
            list(
              orderable = FALSE, 
              className = "details-control", 
              targets = 0
            ),
            list(
              className = "dt-left", 
              targets = "_all"
            )
          )
        )
        
      )      },
    server = F)
    
    
    observeEvent(input$remove_button_Tab1, {
      myTable <- values$tab
      s <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$remove_button_Tab1, "_")[[1]][2])
      myTable <- filter(myTable, id != s)
      replaceData(proxyTable, myTable, resetPaging = FALSE)
      values$tab <- myTable
    })
    
    list_results <- reactive({
      list_values <- list()
      for (i in unique( values$tab$let_rowid)) {
        list_values[[i]] <- paste0(i, ": ", input[[i]])

      }
      list_values
    })

    output$sel = renderPrint({
      list_results()
    })
    
    
    
    ####################################
    ## this simpler version does work ##
    ####################################
    
    
    # removed for now
    
    
  }
)
```

#### One more thing I tried (but did not work)

I now also tried the solution given here: https://stefanengineering.com/2019/07/06/delete-rows-from-shiny-dt-datatable/, but that gives the exact same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assign the wrong `id` element in your JavaScript callback, because in your Table, the first column is actually the `&oplus` column, but you want the second column.

Thus change this

```
table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
   var $this = $(this.node());
   $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]); // this.data()[0] refers to the firts column, i.e. &oplus;
   $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
});
```

to this:

```
table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
   var $this = $(this.node());
   $this.attr('id', this.data()[1]); // the id is in the second column in your case
   $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That in this case does indeed solve my problem in this example. However, is there a way to make this behaviour more predictable (for example by not assigning by index)? For example, if I add two different types of buttons to the table, it still breaks (in the new example, once I click on remove, the radio buttons no longer work.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept these answer and post a new question.

Comment: It indeed solved my problem in the narrow sense, that it worked for the MWE, but not the underlying question on how to add multiple types of JS code to a DT and have them all working consistantly.